# What is a good and known JavaScript MVC pattern?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

What is the best way to manage the JavaScript files and the functions/objects context in an ASP.NET MVC app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google says http://javascriptmvc.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something like that, you should definitely check out [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) as they implement classes almost exactly the way you describe. Overall, I've found their approach to be very clean, extensible, and maintainable. For example, here is a class template I use to write all of my classes (note that it uses some MooTools-specific syntax):

```
var className = new Class ({

    Implements: [Events, Options],

    options: {
        option1: 'option1',
        option2: 'option2'
    },

    initialize: function(options){
        this.setOptions(options);
    },

    function1: function(){

    },

    function2: function(){

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I put all my js files in the Content/Js folder. Then add URL helpers that allow me to change this in the future. My code isn't online, but I stole the idea from [Rob Conery MVC Commerce demo](https://mvcsamples.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Commerce.Web/App/Helpers/AppHelper.cs).

Not sure what you mean by "manage...the functions/objects context in ASp.NET MVC app"

I think you're asking how to segment/partition your scripts. 
You should separate your JS files into separate chunks of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

i'm thinking about a main js file that
is responsible for all the calls of js function like:

```
mainApp = function(){

   return {

       init: function(){

       },

       function1: function(){

       }

   };

};
```

nut in a way of it fits an mvc app.

Answer (score 0):

yes , but this is not a MooTools unique technique,

this is called [Object literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_literal) pattern.

i'm looking for a way to manage my ajax app according to the current state od the asp.net mvc