# Is it possible to apply MVC pattern to javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

Is it possible to apply MVC pattern to javascript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course it is.

For instance, you can take a look at [JavaScript MVC](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/javascript-mvc/).

And, on SO :

- [What would you suggest for a Javascript MVC framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325900/what-would-you-suggest-for-a-javascript-mvc-framework)
- [What is a good and known JavaScript MVC pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216674/what-is-a-good-and-known-javascript-mvc-pattern)
- [Is there a Javascript MVC (micro-)framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386885/is-there-a-javascript-mvc-micro-framework)

Answer (score 2):

MVC is a general concept that can be implemented by any language ...

Answer (score 1):

Use [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/)

These are the three features that make Ember a joy to use:

1. Bindings
2. Computed properties
3. Auto-updating templates

#### Bindings

Use bindings to keep properties between two different objects in sync. You just declare a binding once, and Ember will make sure changes get propagated in either direction.

Here's how you create a binding between two objects:

```
MyApp.president = Ember.Object.create({
  name: "Barack Obama"
});

MyApp.country = Ember.Object.create({
  // Ending a property with 'Binding' tells Ember to
  // create a binding to the presidentName property.
  presidentNameBinding: 'MyApp.president.name'
});

MyApp.country.get('presidentName');
// "Barack Obama"
```

Bindings allow you to architect your application using the MVC (Model-View-Controller) pattern, then rest easy knowing that data will always flow correctly from layer to layer.

#### Computed Properties

Computed properties allow you to treat a function like a property.
Computed properties are useful because they can work with bindings, just like any other property.

#### Auto-updating Templates

Ember uses Handlebars, a semantic templating library. To take data from your JavaScript application and put it into the DOM, create a  tag and put it into your HTML, wherever you'd like the value to appear:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  The President of the United States is {{MyApp.president.fullName}}.
</script>
```